# Remove key from json list in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have json list in table like:

```
[{ "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3 }, {"a":1, "b":2, "a":3}]
```

And i want remove all "a" keys. How i can do it?

I tried this:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET list = list::jsonb - 'a'
```

But it is not working.

I want this result:

```
[{"b": 2, "c": 3 }, {"b":2}]
```

Comment: List column type is json

Comment: Can you add `, {"a";3}` to the input data, and also adjust the expected result (if needed.)

Comment: Yes, I add this.

Comment: May I edit? (I wasn't clear enough.)

Comment: Okey (if you can).

Comment: Never mind, you have already been answered below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it.

```
UPDATE mytable
SET list=(
  SELECT jsonb_agg(elem - 'a')::json
  FROM jsonb_array_elements(list::jsonb) elem
)
```

Comment: "function jsonb_array_elements(json) does not exist"

Comment: Welcome.  I was working with jsonb field on first post and edited for json when realizing.